# Confusing example of nested cross validation in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm looking at this example from scikit-learn documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

It seems to me that crossvalidation is not performed in an unbiased way here. Both `GridSearchCV` (supposedly the inner CV loop) and `cross_val_score` (supposedly the outer CV loop) are using the same data and the same folds. Therefore there is an overlap between the data the classifier was trained on and evaluated with. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4):

@Gael - As I cannot add a comment, I am posting this in the answer section. I am not sure what Gael means by *"the first split is done inside cross_val_score, and the second split is done inside GridSearchCV (that the whole point of the GridSearchCV object)"*. Are you trying to imply that the cross_val_score function passes the (k-1)-fold data (used for training in outer loop) to the clf object ? That does not appear to be the case, as I can comment out the cross_val_score function and just set nested_score[i] to a dummy variable, and still obtain the exact same clf.best_score_. This implies that the GridSearchCV is evaluated separately and does use **all** available data, and not a subset of training data.

In nested CV, to the best of my understanding, the idea is that the inner loop will do the hyper-parameter search on a smaller subset of training data, and then the outer loop will use these parameters to do a cross-validation. One of the reasons for using smaller training data in the inner loop is to avoid information leakage. It doesn't appear that's what is happening here. The inner loop is first using all the data to search for hyper-parameters, which are then used for cross-validation in the outer loop. Thus, the inner loop has already seen all data and any testing done in the outer loop will suffer from information leakage. If I am mistaken, could you please point me to the section of code which you are referring to in your answer ?

Comment: Great comment, but unfortunately it will get moderated away on account of not actually being an answer. Please just earn some points and return to place this comment!

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree, that nested-cv procedure is wrong, cross_val_score is taken the best hyperparameters computed by GridSearchCV and computing a cv score using such hyperparameters. In nested-cv, you need the outer loop for assessing model performance and the inner loop for model selection, such that,  the portion of data used in the inner loop for model selection must not be the same used for assessing model performance. An example will be a LOOCV outer loop for assessing performance (or, it will be a 5cv, 10cv, or whatever you like) and a   10cv-fold  for model selection with grid search in the inner loop. That means that,  if you have N observations then you will perform model selection in the inner loop (using grid search and 10-CV, for example) on the N-1 observations, and you will asses the model performance on the LOO observation (or in the hold-out data sample if you choose another approach).
(Note that you are estimating N best models in the sense of hyperparameters internally) .
it will be helpful to have access to the link of the code of cross_val_score and GridSearchCV.
Some references for nested CV are:

- Christophe Ambroise and Georey J McLachlan. Selection bias in gene extraction on the basis of microarray gene-expression data. Proceedings of the national academy of sciences 99, 10 (2002), 6562 - 6566.
- Gavin C Cawley and Nicola LC Talbot. On overfitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation. Journal of Machine Learning Research 11, Jul (2010), 2079{2107.

Note:
I did not find anything in the documentation of cross_val_score indicating that internally the hyperparameters are optimized using parameter search, grid search + cross-validation for example, on the k-1 folds of data, and using those optimized parameters on the hold-out data sample (what I am saying is different to the code in http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html)

Answer (score 0):

They are not using the same data. Granted, the code of the example does not make it apparent, because the splits are not visible: the first split is done inside cross_val_score, and the second split is done inside GridSearchCV (that the whole point of the GridSearchCV object). Using functions and objects rather than hand-written for loops may make things less transparent, but it:

1. Enables reuses
2. Adds many "little things" that would render the for loop tedious, such as parallel computing, support for different scoring function, etc.
3. Is actually safer in terms of avoid data leakage because our splitting code has been audited many many times.

If you are not convinced, take a look at the code of cross_val_score and GridSearchCV.

The example was improved recently to specify this in the comments:
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

(pull request on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7949 )

Comment: This may add a variation to the data which are used but they will still have great overlapping. The point of nested cross validation is to have entirely separable training and validation tests for GridSearch and test set for cross validation evaluation.